# Forming an sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I really hope that you can help me forming an sql query that can do the following:

I have 2 tables

```
Pages 
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

Contents 
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PageId] [int] NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

Id |   Key   | CreatedAt | Title
---+---------+-----------+-------
 1 | "page1" | 20200101  | ....


Id | PageId |   Key  | Version | Text 
---+--------+--------+---------+------
 1 |    1   | "key1" |    1    | .....
 2 |    1   | "key1" |    2    | .....
 3 |    1   | "key2" |    1    | .....
 4 |    1   | "key2" |    2    | .....
 5 |    1   | "key3" |    1    | .....
```

I'm interested in getting the page and the newest version of each content where `PageId` matches the page.

** Update **

Key is the key that is passed to get the result

```
Select * from Pages where [Key] = 'the key of the page'
```

The desired result would be something like

```
Page.Id | Page.Key | Page.CreatedAt | Page.Title | Content.Id | Content.PageId | Content.Key | Content.Version | Content.Text
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |  "Page1" |    20200101    |   ......   |     2      |        1       |    "Key1"     |    2     | ......
   1    |  "Page1" |    20200101    |   ......   |     4      |        1       |    "Key2"     |    2     | ......
   1    |  "Page1" |    20200101    |   ......   |     5      |        1       |    "Key3"     |    1     | ......
```

Comment: Thank you for the table structures and data. What are you having trouble with? You forgot to post your query. A model of your desired result set would also be helpful.

Comment: What do the columns in both tables called 'Key' do? What does it mean that page 1 has 2 versions for "Key1" and for "Key2" and maybe more?

Comment: @EricBrandt I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

We need more info. 
To get the newest results, you can order your output and limit the number of results like below:

```
SELECT PageID FROM Contents WHERE PageID=$pageid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: That's not Transact SQL syntax. Note the `tsql` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If by newest you mean the max version then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select p.*, c.* 
from Pages p 
left join (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by PageId, [Key] order by version desc) rn
  from Contents
) c on c.PageId = p.Id and c.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17199e135a5c00435881e182ddd611b7).